# PHP how to extract 3 digits from a string and output it

Tags: php, regex

This is a bit a strange issue. I am trying just to get sequential 3 digit integer from a string.

Now I thought I was successfully doing it using this code below...

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $image['title'], $integer); echo $integer[0][2];
```

But now it seems to be failing on some strings.

It works fine on these strings...

1. TZR9000 Supertroop 2014 001
2. FZR Mode 900 Impact 2014 003 Accessories
3. NICE750 Destroyer 2014 020

But then it fails on this string...

1. We like the moon 2013 Stand 010

Is there another possible way to extract the 3 digit integer successfully with out getting confused with other integers. I guess it will have to be a clever bit of php to do this.

The only consistent pattern there is, is there is always a space infront of the 3 digits and either a full-stop or a space after the 3 digits.

Comment: Items 2 and 3 both have two 3-digit strings; which is the one that you're looking for?

Comment: From your example, what 3 digits do you want? 3 or more digits? Exactly 3 digits? Multiple sets of 3 digits?

Comment: The 3 digits at the end, not the 3 digits that are part of the model names.

Comment: `$integer[0][2]` is displaying the 3rd match (0,1,2) of digit sets; but in the string where it fails only has 2 digits sets.... perhaps that might be why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solidest way should be

```
preg_match_all('!(\d{3})(?=(?:(?!\d{3}).)*$)!m', $str, $integer);
```

see it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/pJ0xN4

here's also a structural explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the exact requirements, but in the examples you have given, you just need the last element of the array, so you can replace:

```
echo $integer[0][2];
```

with:

```
echo end($integer[0]);
```

Comment: Yes jeroen this works. Thanks you dude. So end counts back the array

Comment: @Joshc According to the manual: `end() advances array's internal pointer to the last element, and returns its value.`

Answer (score 0):

The current regex extracts all the digit-sequences in the title. In order to extract only the last three digits we can use a regex that grabs only the last sequence in the title (space before and "end of the line" = `$`) - we'll always have the result in the first item of the result array:

```
$str = "TZR9000 Supertroop 2014 001";
preg_match_all('! (\d+)$!', $str, $integer); 
echo $integer[0][0];

$str = "We like the moon 2013 Stand 010";
preg_match_all('! (\d+)$!', $str, $integer); 
echo $integer[0][0];
```

**OUTPUT:**
001 010